# Error importing modules in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I've just installed Python 2.7.8 (as default version) following [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu). I was using Python 2.7.6 before this. I have been importing modules such as pyglet, gasp and pygame normally. Now, I can't import any of these (whenever I try, I get

> No module named (some module)

error). I haven't changed anything. Each of these are properly installed. I even removed (with all dependencies) and installed pyglet again, but problem remained. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are installing the modules under new Python installation directory?

You need to install all the modules for the new Python version.

- Check under your `Python2.7.8` installation directory `<PYTHON2.7.8_INSTALL_DIR>\Lib\site-packages\` whether you have all the needed modules or not.
- To install into the modules under the new Python, use the new `easy_install.exe` or `pip.exe` under `<PYTHON2.7.8_INSTALL_DIR>\Scripts`

Comment: I would really like to do what you said, but I'm not sure whether I know how to. If you can, please provide some step-by-step guide for me what to do. @sk11

Comment: Where do you install your Python2.7.8? And where was your Python2.7.6 was installed?

Comment: I would like if I know what to answer. I followed this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/101591/how-do-i-install-python-2-7-2-on-ubuntu (first answer).

Comment: Tell me how to check. @sk11

Comment: Try `whereis python2.7.8` and `whereis python2.7.6`

Comment: check this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/262063/how-to-find-python-installation-directory-on-ubuntu

Comment: python2.7.8:/usr/bin/python AND
python2.7.6:/usr/bin/python2.7
What now? @sk11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59642/discussion-between-muhamed-huseinbasic-and-sk11).